# Library for converting projection transformation in PHP

Tags: coordinate-system, php, proj, utm, online

I would like to transform data from lat/long ETRS89 to y/x UTM ETRS89 through PHP.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A internet search on PHP and projection turned up a PHP port for PROJ.4.

[proj4php](https://github.com/proj4php/proj4php)

The page says that it's a translation from a Javascript version of PROJ.4. I'm not familiar with it so I can't give you any more details.

Comment: [_"This project has no files."_](http://sourceforge.net/projects/proj4php/files/?source=navbar)

Comment: https://github.com/proj4php/proj4php